# Do rxjs Subject and EventEmitter affect performance in Angular?

Tags: angular

I am trying to pass an event to a child component from the parent.

My code looks somewhat like this

Parent Component HTML:
...

```
<child-component [validate]="emitValidateAsObservable">
<child-component [validate]="emitValidateAsObservable">
<child-component [validate]="emitValidateAsObservable">
...
```

Parent Component TS:

```
emitValidate = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
emitValidateAsObservable: Observable<boolean>;

constructor(...){
    this.emitValidateAsObservable = this.emitValidate.asObservable();
}

public onSubmit(): void {
    this.emitValidate.emit(true);
}
```

The EventEmitter was initially a Subject. But either way, this code works but the issue is I see a performance drag. I understand that I am passing the observable to 3 child components but is this expected - just for 3?

Please take a look at the performance I recorded in the console. When I hit submit on the parent, it takes about 451ms for handling it. Is this normal?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAwre.png)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to pass data from parent component to child, you can achieve it using @input decorator which will be slight faster when compared to Subject. but the issue is you need to create new memory instance by using Object.create or array.splice().

If you use subject, we are passing the observable data from parent to child component.

Here is the stackblitz comparison for both, seeing 5 millisecond difference.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nup6pw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score -1):

```
Observables cause memory leaks if they are not unsubscribed.
```

Create a service with an observable (same as above but in a service file).

```
@Injectable()
export class DemoService() {
//create an observable
emitValidateAsObservable
}
```

Provide the service in the parent module or in the component.

Inject these service in the component where subscription is required.

subscibe to the service.

```
constructor(private demoService: DemoService) {}
ngOnInIt() {
this.demoService.emitValidateAsObservable.subscribe(() => {});
}
```

For performance issues (memory-leaks), use must always unsubscribe observables at

```
ngOnDestroy(){
 this.demoService.emitValidateAsObservable.unsubscribe();
}
```

Hope these works, you can track memory leaks through google dev tools (chrome f12, ctrl + shft+ I)